# Angular 8 - Reactive form is not being populated when calling form.setValue()

Tags: angular, rest, angular-material

I'm displaying a list of employee records (Employee-ListComponent) in Angular Material with two action buttons (edit & delete) as well as a 'create' button which allows me to create a new entry (EmployeeComponent). When clicking 'edit' a form pops up and I want to populate the same form that is being rendered in 'create' with the respective employee data in the row. I have function in my service.ts which is being called in employee-list.ts onEdit() which successfully populates a form with the right data as far as I can see in the console:

```
  populateForm(employee) {
    this.form.setValue(employee);
    console.log(this.form.controls['$key'].value);
  }
```

However, when calling

```
 this.dialog.open(EmployeeComponent,dialogConfig);
```

I the pop up window still renders an empty form. 
What am I missing to make EmployeeComponent realize the change in the form?

My initial form is defined in the service file too.
I'm new to Angular / reactive forms, but I was wondering why the employee.component.ts file is not subscribed to listen to any changes in service.form

*See relevant parts:*

*Employee-List.comnponent.ts*

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.service.get_employees().subscribe(
      res => {
        var list = res;
        //console.log(list);
        let array = list.map(item => {
          return {
            $key: item.employeeid,
            ...item
          }
        });
        this.listData = new MatTableDataSource(array);
        console.log(this.listData)
    });
  }

  onEdit(row){
    console.log(row)
    this.service.populateForm(row);
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    dialogConfig.disableClose = false;
    dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
    dialogConfig.width = "60%";
    this.dialog.open(EmployeeComponent,dialogConfig);
  }
```

*Employee.comnponent.ts*

```
export class EmployeeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private service: EmployeeService,
    private notificationService: NotificationService,
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<EmployeeComponent>) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.get_employees().subscribe();
  }
```

*employee.component.html*

```
<form [formGroup]="service.form" class="normal-form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="700px">
            <mat-grid-tile>
                <div class="controles-container">
                    <input type="hidden" formControlName="$key">
```

*employee-list.component.html*

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
                        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></mat-header-cell>
                        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
                            <button mat-icon-button (click)="onEdit(row)"><mat-icon>launch</mat-icon></button>
                            <button mat-icon-button color="warn" (click)="onDelete(row.$key)"><mat-icon>delete_outline</mat-icon></button>                        </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

*employee.service.ts*

```
  form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    $key: new FormControl(null),
    fullName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    email: new FormControl('', Validators.email),
    mobile: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]),
    city: new FormControl(''),
    gender: new FormControl('1'),
    department: new FormControl(0),
    hireDate: new FormControl(''),
    isPermanent: new FormControl(false)
  });

 // First a function to retrieve all the records
  get_employees(): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + "/api/employees/", this.httpOptions);
  }

  populateForm(employee) {
    this.form.setValue(employee);
    console.log(this.form.controls['$key'].value);
  }
```

The log in populateForm()shows it has the correct key value, but the form in the pop up is being rendered as if the $key = null

Realize that this is kind of similar to:

1. [Populating/patching values of angular reactive forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49057998/populating-patching-values-of-angular-reactive-forms)
2. [Angular 5 - Reactive Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55797253/angular-5-reactive-forms)
3. [Populating Angular Reactive Forms correcctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55373087/populating-angular-reactive-forms-correcctly)

Thank you!

======== Update  ========

I added

```
private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<QuestionComponent>,
@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any
```

to the constructor in employee.component.ts & upon logging the object that is injected in ngOnInit() {} I can see that it grabs the right data it needs to populate the form. 
But the popup form is still not being populated with it. Can someone get me out of the dark please?

Comment: make your service public if using it in template.

Comment: Thanks, Brian. Makes sense to me, but didn't change anything.. you were referring to the part where I inject service in my constructor right?

Comment: can you try with patchValue(value), I believe setValue(value) does not work unless you are setting all the formcontrol values

Comment: actually that might not be the problem, can you make a stackblitz? It actually looks like you arent grabbing the data you are sending to your dialog at all? When you opeenDialog you send the data in correctly sure, but I dont see where you collect it back. You need to use MAT_DIALOG_DATA

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sfm9a2  check out this stackblitz